# Generate raw output with headers and block separators in JQ

Tags: json, jq, zimbra

Using JQ, I need to convert JSON objects to a very specific format called `zmp`, which looks like this:

```
selectMailbox     user.one@domain.com
modifyFolderFlags /Inbox       ""
modifyFolderFlags /Inbox/teste ""

selectMailbox     user.two@domain.com.br
modifyFolderFlags /Inbox ""
modifyFolderFlags /Sent  ""
```

With this program:

```
jq -r '.. | objects | select(.flags == "i" or .flags == "#i") | "selectMailbox \(input_filename)","modifyFolderFlags \(.path) \"\" "' *
```

I was able to output:

```
selectMailbox     user.one@domain.com
modifyFolderFlags /Inbox       ""
selectMailbox     user.one@domain.com
modifyFolderFlags /Inbox/teste ""
selectMailbox     user.two@domain.com.br
modifyFolderFlags /Inbox ""
selectMailbox     user.two@domain.com.br
modifyFolderFlags /Sent  ""
```

As you see, it outputs `selectMailbox` multiple times and it's missing the block separator (blank line).

Below are sample inputs.

`/tmp/jq/user.one@domain.com`

```
{
  "path": "/",
  "subFolders": [
    {
      "flags": "#",
      "path": "/Drafts",
      "subFolders": []
    },
    {
      "flags": "#i",
      "path": "/Inbox",
      "subFolders": [
        {
          "flags": "i",
          "path": "/Inbox/teste",
          "subFolders": []
        }
      ],
      "unreadCount": 0
    },
    {
      "path": "/Sent",
      "subFolders": []
    }
  ],
  "unreadCount": 0
}
```

`/tmp/jq/user.two@domain.com.br`

```
{
  "path": "/",
  "subFolders": [
    {
      "flags": "#i",
      "path": "/Inbox",
      "subFolders": []
    },
    {
      "flags": "#i",
      "path": "/Sent",
      "subFolders": []
    },
    {
      "flags": "#",
      "path": "/Trash",
      "subFolders": []
    }
  ],
  "unreadCount": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You was very close of the solution .

When you have a list of files , you can use `jq -slurp`  to create a big array with all contents of your files .

But because in your case you care about the filename a alternative is concatenate the content of file with the filename in one object .

in your case for example :

```
jq  -r '{"email":input_filename} + .' *
```

and after you can apply almost your solution

```
jq  -r '{"email":input_filename} + . | 
        "selectMailbox \(.email)",
          (..|objects | select(.flags == "i" or .flags == "#i") |
                          "modifyFolderFlags \(.path) \"\" " 
          ),"" ' *
```